# Ubuntu freezes while loading desk

Tags: boot, freeze

My computer always get frozen after logging in my ubuntu account. It happens on every account and even when it loads cinnamon. I have to shut it down by pressing the power button and just then i can use my notebook normally. Can anyone please help me? Im new to ubuntu, id ve very thankful with any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot with an old kernel. I have the same problem and I realized that with kernel version 3.0 the booting process goes smoothly. Also , can you say your version of Ubuntu please.